# How do I remove bottom borders from accordion patterns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a code for website with accordion patters and can't figure out how do I remove border from the "bottom section" of the accordion pattern. I need to have borders on top section that opens the rest of accordion patter onclick. Anyone knows? Tried searching for it and could not find anything.

Here's my code :

```html
<section id="specification" class="mt-5 pt-4">
    <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-shorter">
        <!--Accordion wrapper-->
        <div class="accordion md-accordion accordion-1" id="accordionEx23" role="tablist">
            <div class="card my-4">
                <div class="card-header blue lighten-3 z-depth-1" role="tab" id="heading96">
                    <h4 class="text-capitalize mb-0 py-1">
                        <a class="text-black font-weight-light" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse96" aria-expanded="true"
                           aria-controls="collapse96">
                            kupní typ
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse96" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading96"
                     data-parent="#accordionEx23">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <h6 class="font-weight-light black-text text-grey mb-5">Sponsorship</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

I tried adding additional CSS such as :

```css
.card-body{
    border: none !important;
}
.collapse{
    border: none !important;
}
```

I expect the above CSS properties to overwrite the border but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Anyone knows how can I remove the border for the section below the clickable text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the border, you have to target .card-header,
so the css would look like:

```
.card-header {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

for the bottom, you have to edit the card itself:

```
.card {
    border: none !important;
}
```

please let me know if this works :)

Comment: Hmm super strange. Now the border doesn't show up until I click the actual accordion pattern and then it show on the bottom of the button only. I've checked if there are no additional border classes in my CSS but there are not. Pretty sure that is a fault on my side tho!

Comment: You can remove the body border, then add in a head border, does that work? https://codepen.io/herbglitch24/pen/rNNXWPw

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks so much to all contributors!